# postgres accessing field in RECORD type variable by text variables

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in Postgresql and I want to select from a table and insert into another table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."update_table"("table_name" varchar, "key_col" varchar, "title_col" varchar)
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."bool" AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        temprow record;
    BEGIN

    FOR temprow IN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT '|| table_key ||', '|| table_title ||' FROM '|| table_name
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO coding(title, code,"parent_code") VALUES ('|| temprow.title_col ||', '|| temprow.key_col ||', 2);';
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 't';
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

there is an error for accessing temprow value with key_col variable , how can I access to this fields?

```
ERROR:  record "temprow" has no field "table_title"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop or a temporary record variable, just use an `INSERT ... SELECT`

Additionally: when you are dealing with dynamic SQL, you should always use the `format()` function and `%I` placeholders for table and column names to properly deal with quoting.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."update_table"("table_name" varchar, "key_col" varchar, "title_col" varchar)
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."bool" AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO coding (title, code, "parent_code") 
                    SELECT %I, %I, 2 
                    FROM %I', table_key, table_title, table_name'); 

    RETURN 't';
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

Comment: I need to insert into coding table for each row of first select so I need a loop to getting data from table_name and inserting to coding table

Comment: No, you do not need a loop - the `SELECT` will retrieve all rows from the table and all those rows will be inserted into the coding table. A loop is definitely **not** needed here.

Comment: Ok I got it and your answer is true but if I want to access to fields of record with another text variable , how can i do that?